# Show progress whilst using Android MediaMuxer. How to get total file(content) size?

Tags: android, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

I’m muxing an audio and video file.
I have the urls where both files are hosted.
I use [android.media.MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) and [android.media.MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor) to mux them.
During this muxing, those classes download the files, but I want to show progress, **so I need to know the total file size of the audio file and the video files**.

Does anyone know how to get the file size using those Android API’s? Or do I have to just hit the URL’s myself (again) to get the content length?

Example files

Video url: https://v.redd.it/832kzf6e23h71/DASH_1080.mp4

Audio url: https://v.redd.it/832kzf6e23h71/DASH_audio.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did a HEAD request to get the "content-length" header (which gives me the file size), before handing off to MediaExtractor.

I've realised now I could also have downloaded the file myself, then get a local `FileDescriptor` and pass that to `MediaExtractor` allowing me to avoid extra network requests.